# jquery clone the content of a div on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to clone an element inside a div and append it to another div without any click event, on page load. This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="hs-search-results__listing">
   <li>
     <a href="#" class="hs-search-results__title">Search Title</a>
     <p class="more-link-container">
      &nbsp;
     </p>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#" class="hs-search-results__title">Search Title</a>
     <p class="more-link-container">
      &nbsp;
     </p>
   </li>
</ul>


<script>
  $('.hs-search-results__listing li').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.hs-search-results__title').clone().appendTo(".more-link-container");
  });
</script>
```

I am trying the above but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration you are appending to all the elements with class *more-link-container* available in the DOM. You should append the element only to the relevant *p* element.

Change

```
.appendTo(".more-link-container")
```

To

```
.appendTo($(this).find(".more-link-container"))
```

```js
$('.hs-search-results__listing li').each(function(){
  $(this).find('.hs-search-results__title').clone().appendTo($(this).find(".more-link-container"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="hs-search-results__listing">
   <li>
     <a href="#" class="hs-search-results__title">Search Title</a>
     <p class="more-link-container">
      &nbsp;
     </p>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#" class="hs-search-results__title">Search Title</a>
     <p class="more-link-container">
      &nbsp;
     </p>
   </li>
</ul>
```